# Django default session

Tags: python, django

I want to give user some default session when joining website, without pressing anything.One way is to include request.session['lang']='en' at the home page class but what if first time joining user tries to access another class.

Answer (score 0):

There's not really much point in this. Sessions implement the dictionary interface, so you can always get a default when you access the key:

```
lang = request.session.get('lang', 'en')
```

which will return the lang stored in the session or 'en' if there is none.